# Error registering service to eureka server

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am trying to register a client to spring-eureka-server, client deregisters just after registering

eureka-server logs:

> 2018-05-13 16:02:47.290  INFO 25557 --- [io-9091-exec-10]
>   c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance
>   HELLO-CLIENT/192.168.43.96:hello-client:8072 with status UP
>   (replication=false) 2018-05-13 16:02:47.438  INFO 25557 ---
>   [nio-9091-exec-3] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  :
>   Registered instance HELLO-CLIENT/192.168.43.96:hello-client:8072 with
>   status DOWN (replication=false) 2018-05-13 16:02:47.457  INFO 25557
>   --- [nio-9091-exec-2] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Cancelled instance HELLO-CLIENT/192.168.43.96:hello-client:8072
>   (replication=false) 2018-05-13 16:02:47.950  INFO 25557 ---
>   [nio-9091-exec-5] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  :
>   Registered instance HELLO-CLIENT/192.168.43.96:hello-client:8072 with
>   status DOWN (replication=true) 2018-05-13 16:02:47.951  INFO 25557 ---
>   [nio-9091-exec-5] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Cancelled
>   instance HELLO-CLIENT/192.168.43.96:hello-client:8072
>   (replication=true) 2018-05-13 16:03:25.747  INFO 25557 ---
>   [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running
>   the evict task with compensationTime 4ms

Eureka-client logs:

> 2018-05-13 16:02:47.163  INFO 25676 --- [nfoReplicator-0]
>   com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    :
>   DiscoveryClient_HELLO-CLIENT/192.168.43.96:hello-client:8072:
>   registering service... 2018-05-13 16:02:47.212  INFO 25676 --- [
>   main] c.a.helloclient.HelloClientApplication   : Started
>   HelloClientApplication in 7.62 seconds (JVM running for 8.573)
>   2018-05-13 16:02:47.224  INFO 25676 --- [       Thread-5]
>   s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6f7923a5:
>   startup date [Sun May 13 16:02:42 IST 2018]; parent:
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5c30a9b0
>   2018-05-13 16:02:47.226  INFO 25676 --- [       Thread-5]
>   o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Unregistering application
>   hello-client with eureka with status DOWN 2018-05-13 16:02:47.227 
>   WARN 25676 --- [       Thread-5] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient
>   : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent
>   [timestamp=1526207567227, current=DOWN, previous=UP] 2018-05-13
>   16:02:47.232  INFO 25676 --- [       Thread-5]
>   o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
>   2018-05-13 16:02:47.235  INFO 25676 --- [       Thread-5]
>   com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Shutting down
>   DiscoveryClient ... 2018-05-13 16:02:47.292  INFO 25676 ---
>   [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    :
>   DiscoveryClient_HELLO-CLIENT/192.168.43.96:hello-client:8072 -
>   registration status: 204 2018-05-13 16:02:47.423  INFO 25676 ---
>   [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    :
>   DiscoveryClient_HELLO-CLIENT/192.168.43.96:hello-client:8072:
>   registering service... 2018-05-13 16:02:47.440  INFO 25676 ---
>   [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    :
>   DiscoveryClient_HELLO-CLIENT/192.168.43.96:hello-client:8072 -
>   registration status: 204 2018-05-13 16:02:47.442  INFO 25676 --- [
>   Thread-5] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Unregistering ...
>   2018-05-13 16:02:47.460  INFO 25676 --- [       Thread-5]
>   com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    :
>   DiscoveryClient_HELLO-CLIENT/192.168.43.96:hello-client:8072 -
>   deregister  status: 200 2018-05-13 16:02:47.494  INFO 25676 --- [
>   Thread-5] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Completed shut
>   down of DiscoveryClient 2018-05-13 16:02:47.495  INFO 25676 --- [
>   Thread-5] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering
>   JMX-exposed beans on shutdown 2018-05-13 16:02:47.498  INFO 25676 ---
>   [       Thread-5] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        :
>   Unregistering JMX-exposed beans

Please let me know what could be possibly wrong.

Comment: Your client application is starting, registering with eureka server, and then something shuts it down. So before shutting down, the instance de-registers from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a dependency issue.

If the app works fine (the core functionality) without eureka integration, then try changing the `eureka-client` dependency version.

Answer (score 19):

Add

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

into Eureka and client app

It really works !!!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @DieterMeemken  probably this answer can clear your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22409655/3802053

Comment: seriously, i almost wasted 2 1/2 hours with this error, and finally add this dependency and removed it, then all works fine

Answer (score 3):

Eureka client deregisters when an app has been shutdown.

Check if there is any other reason why the app is stopping leading to eureka-client deregistering.

For my case, the application was shutting down due to `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency. After resolving this, the application started well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check the following:

1. Check all the port numbers that you are running
2. Check for any version issues
3. Add above web dependency in your eureka pom.xml (it worked for me in Maven projects)