# There is no known eureka server; cluster server list is empty

Tags: spring

2024-02-08 18:42:28.545 ERROR 8768 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_ZUUL-API-GATEWAY/dev:zuul-api-gateway:8011 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = There is no known eureka server; cluster server list is empty how to correct this erreur in zull project

2024-02-08 18:42:28.545 ERROR 8768 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_ZUUL-API-GATEWAY/dev:zuul-api-gateway:8011 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = There is no known eureka server; cluster server list is empty how to correct this erreur in zull projet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error registering service to eureka server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315195/error-registering-service-to-eureka-server)